# x86 Assembly how to use DIV instruction and loop to check if integer is prime

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, irvine32

I've created a procedure that will print all the prime numbers up to the user input. However, some of the output values are not prime such as 15, 21 etc. If I begin the program with 15, it will not output it as prime, so it must be my DIV segment or loop. Any help is much appreciated.

```
.code
main proc



mov ecx, 18             ;ecx is the loop counter
mov eax, 2              ;assume 2 is prime
L1:
    inc eax             ;start with value 3
    call isPrime
    loop L1


invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp

isPrime PROC          ;Procedure
push eax
push ecx
mov valEntered, eax
mov ogCounter, ecx


mov edx, 0            ;check if 
                      ;value divisible by 2
mov eax, eax
div divisor0          ;divisor0 = 2
mov eax, edx
cmp eax, 0
jz no   


mov ecx, valEntered         ;ecx loop 
                            ;counter

L2:              ;check if 
                 ;value divisible by >= 3
mov eax, iStart  ;iStart = 3
mul iStart
cmp valEntered, eax
jl yes

mov edx, 0
mov eax, valEntered
div iStart      ;iStart = 3
mov eax, edx
cmp eax, 0
jz no       
add iStart, 2   ;iStart += 2
loop L2
jmp no


yes:                ;output prime number
mov eax, valEntered
call WriteInt
call Crlf
mov ecx, ogCounter
pop ecx
pop eax
ret

no:                ;continue to next int
mov ecx, ogCounter
pop ecx
pop eax
ret

isPrime ENDP
end main
```

Comment: related: [Checking if a number is prime in NASM Win64 Assembly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/204965) for style and efficiency.  Never use `div` when you know the divisor is a power of 2.  And you definitely don't need to keep a divisor in memory; use registers; that's what they're for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change `iStart` when checking for a prime but you never reset it back to 3 for the next check.